# What computer spec would be good video editing

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, computer-building, desktop-computer, video-editing

I wanna buy a computer to use it as website/graphic design also a little video editing (After Effects).  I still not sure about choosing between laptop or desktop.  So what spec would do the job for me.  I'm not looking for an overkilling system as my budget isn't that much. But still something that works for me.
For example what about this:

- intel i5
- 6GB RAM
- GTX 660 2GB

I'm not a pro in computer building so I need someone to help me and advice me about a system for the described usage.

Comment: We do not do shopping recomendations.  Video editing requires memory and processing power.  The graphic card wouldn't be a huge performance.  We cannot suggest specific builds for that reason.  I should point out that all the information you need to research to make a good purchase does exist.

Comment: Video editing requires not only memory and processing power, but a lot of HDD space, and fast file reading / writing is crucial too

Comment: Also you would benefit from fast hard drives.  One drive for OS and a second (or more) for work.  Disk I/O is a big bottleneck for video editing

Comment: @Ramhound Actually some modern video editing software benefits more from a good GPU then a faster processor. A GPU offers very fast parallel processing...

Answer (score 2):

There are annual [DIY guides for building systems aimed at video editing](https://www.videoguys.com/Guide/E/Videoguys+DIY9+Its+Time+for+Sandy+Bridge+E+DIY+95+Update/0xe9b142f408a2b03ab88144a434e88de7.aspx) made by the Videoguys site, the latest seems to be from April 2013. There are various different price ranges covered.

I haven't built one myself but have been told about it by more than one professional video editor. I'm not in any way related to the site.

Answer (score 0):

get something entry level even like a modular desktop with windows/ubuntu and you should be fine as long as you have ram and a decent video card. Avoid a laptop unless it is something like mac book pro etc. Cheap laptops that utilize a lot of graphic programs etc will always require a power source and have heat up issues. A small profile desktop that's beefed up on ram and video card should work well.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Do you have any suggestion for the component, like is 8GB ram enough. Or Any particular Video card ? :)